# Connecting from Android device to linux virtual machine on MAC via bluetooth

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth

Let me explain the situation:

1. Web application is running on ubuntu virtual machine (VirtualBox). I can
   ping it from my mac. Vm's ip address is 192.168.56.100.
2. Android device is connected to a mac via bluetooth internet sharing.
   I can ping from android to mac. mac's ip address 192.168.65.1.
3. I can access web application from android if its are running directly on mac (MAMP).

---

The problem: I need to be able to ping from android device to virtual machine.
Don't know what is the best ways to achieve that. I believe i have to set up some sort of network
bridge or IP forwarding or port forwarding or routing rule to virtual machine.

---

This is my virtual box network settings:

http://imageshack.us/a/img42/2475/9ufb.png

http://imageshack.us/a/img24/2319/w4nh.png

Tried to make a bridge network adapter to Bluetooth PAN on virtual box setting
Didn't work.

---

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you solve this problem? I am still struggling...